# Check Domain Availability from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, dns, whois

I'm trying to check domain name availability from my Rails app. Is there a good (free) API to do this with?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whois client for Ruby on Github that seems to be updated regularly:

https://github.com/weppos/whois

The API doesn't look bad, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (and many other operations) using [dnsimple](https://github.com/aetrion/dnsimple-ruby)

But it's not free, it starts at $3/month with a 30 days free trial.

Comment: You should be able to do a domain availability check with DNSimple even without creating an account or an API key.